# How to make this more compact? JQuery image slideshow on hover (video thumbnail preview)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this video preview slideshow function. 
Im new to jquery so i was wondering if there was a better way to do this, it feels clumsy to just have a separate "timers" for each frame and would mean that the number of frames couldnt be changed.
Or is this fine? 
Tequila bottles for the sake of demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay=1500, setTimeoutConst;
    $('.image').hover(function(){
            var id = '#' + this.id;
     setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function(){
            $(id).addClass('hover');
            $(id).attr('src', 'https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-u9ww3di/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/6589/10932/adictivo-botella-anejo-750ml-40alcvol-hd-medal-transparent__55529.1522775464.png');
        }, delay);
   },function(){
 clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst );
   });
   
    var delay2=3000, setTimeoutConst2;
    $('.image').hover(function(){
        var id = '#' + this.id;
     setTimeoutConst2 = setTimeout(function(){
            $(id).attr('src', 'https://products1.imgix.drizly.com/ci-hornitos-reposado-tequila-73ca9c69a1974b3b.jpeg');
        }, delay2);
   },function(){
 clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst2 );
   });
   
    var delay3=4500, setTimeoutConst3;
    $('.image').hover(function(){
        var id = '#' + this.id;
     setTimeoutConst3 = setTimeout(function(){

            $(id).attr('src', 'https://www.wallywine.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/2/12183.jpg');
        }, delay3);
   },function(){
 clearTimeout(setTimeoutConst3 );
   }),
  


    $('.image').mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
            $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.hellowcost.fr/4806-large_default/tiscaz-gold-tequila-35-70-cl.jpg');
    });
});
```

```css
.image {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <img class="image" id='1' src="http://www.hellowcost.fr/4806-large_default/tiscaz-gold-tequila-35-70-cl.jpg" alt=""><br>
    <img class="image" id='2' src="http://www.hellowcost.fr/4806-large_default/tiscaz-gold-tequila-35-70-cl.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your example code and trimmed out some unnecessary bits, and reduced it to one timer so it's cleaner and easier to modify (which I guess was your point).

Firstly it initialises a few variables.  One to store the interval ID (rather than multiple timeouts), an image index so the function knows which image to show next, and then an array of image urls.

The hover function creates the interval and then saves the image's src attribute as a data attribute of that image (so you can set it back to the original image later).

The interval adds 1 to `slideshowIndex`, and sets it back to 0 if it reaches the length of the image array.  This means you can add images to the array (or remove them) and it will always loop correctly.  You'll never have to change the interval function when you change the list of images in the array (which I assume may be dynamic).

All that's left is to handle the hover off function, which clears the interval and sets the image back to its original src.

I left the add & remove hover class code there in case you use it, but it does nothing in this example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slideshowIntervalId = 0;
    var slideshowIndex = 0;
    var slideshowImages = [
        "https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-u9ww3di/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/6589/10932/adictivo-botella-anejo-750ml-40alcvol-hd-medal-transparent__55529.1522775464.png",
        "https://products1.imgix.drizly.com/ci-hornitos-reposado-tequila-73ca9c69a1974b3b.jpeg",
        "https://www.wallywine.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1800x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/2/12183.jpg"
    ];

    $(".image").hover(function() {
        var $image = $(this);
        $image.addClass("hover");
        $image.data("original-src", this.src);
        slideshowIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
            slideshowIndex = ++slideshowIndex % slideshowImages.length;
            $image.attr("src", slideshowImages[slideshowIndex]);
        }, 1500);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        this.src = $(this).data("original-src");
        clearInterval(slideshowIntervalId);
    });

});
```

```css
.image {
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Page Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
    <img class="image" id='1' src="http://www.hellowcost.fr/4806-large_default/tiscaz-gold-tequila-35-70-cl.jpg" alt=""><br>
    <img class="image" id='2' src="http://www.hellowcost.fr/4806-large_default/tiscaz-gold-tequila-35-70-cl.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - glad you like it.  It does raise some questions for me, like how you're planning on actually using it.  If there's more than one instance of this on a page then it will need changing to suit that, for example.  It all depends on the final use case, which I don't know so I've just answered the question as asked.

Comment: I also just noticed I'd left some unnecessary code in there, so I've removed it.

Comment: Oh if youre still wondering, i edited it a bit so i could use it with multiple sets of images on different instances.                                                                                     `$(".thumbnail").hover(function() {
     var id = "http://mywebsite.com/thumbnails/" + this.id;
     var slideshowImages = [
      id + "_1.jpg", 
      id + "_2.jpg",
      id + "_3.jpg",
      id + "_4.jpg",
      id + "_5.jpg",
      id + "_6.jpg"
     ];`